# Why "Terminator Salvation" and not "Terminator: Salvation"?

Tags: title, terminator-salvation, terminator-series

After the success of *The Terminator*, most of the titles of the [franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_%28franchise%29) have followed the "Terminator: subtitle" template. Examples include:

- Terminator 2: Judgment Day
- Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines
- Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles
- Terminator: War of the Machines
- Terminator: Rampage
- Terminator: Future Shock
- Terminator: Dawn of Fate

Then we have [*Terminator Salvation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_Salvation). What is the significance of the missing colon?

Comment: Looks like a new producer/director take.

Comment: The much more interesting question would be, what "Terminator Salvation" actually means (as I for myself don't really know), but maybe this will get answered here as a by-product.

Comment: @ChristianRau ... Terminator Salvation refers to Marcus' redemption in helping the human race against the machines even though he is one.

Comment: @AnkitSharma ... The rights were sold before Terminator 3, so I don't think that would be a reason.

Comment: [Originally](http://collider.com/entertainment/news/article.asp/aid/7984/tcid/1) the titel was: __Terminator Salvation: The Future Begins__ - Btw, the _german_ title does have a colon [Terminator: Die Erlösung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator:_Die_Erlösung)

Comment: @Oliver_C Yet strangely enough the German versions of the previous movies *don't* have a colon (probably because of cultural differences in marking subtitles, but why the colon in *Salvation* then instead of a *"-"*?).

Comment: @ChristianRau - Maybe different distribution companies? German titles for foreign films can range from _odd_ to _downright wrong_, e.g. 'Quigley Down Under' became 'Quigley der Australier' (= Quigley the Australian), but Quigley is actually American(!)

Answer (score 6):

This is because in T2 & T3, what was listed after **Terminator #** was a tag line, so requires a colon. With **Terminator Salvation** it is a single title. You can see it here in the movie posters:

[image: Terminator 2: Judgement Day from Google Images]

[image: Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines from Google Images]

And here with Terminator Salvation you can see it is not a tag line:

[image: Terminator Salvation from Google Images]

Comment: This even seems to be supported by the fact, that it didn't have a sequel number either. While the two previous movies still make sense without the tagline, this doesn't work with *Terminator Salvation*. (Ok, it doesn't work with the TV-show and the other listed things I've never heard of, but well.)

Comment: And "_Salvation_" isn't a tag line. Is that what you are implying? Cause otherwise the title "**Terminator Salvation**" seems to mean _salvation of Terminators_, which frankly, doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Also true. The more important question would be why it wasn't a tagline (if it wasn't) and what the title actually means at all, anyway.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher ... It would not be *Salvation of Terminators* but ***Salvation of Terminator*** ... just one: Marcus.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yet *Marcus* wasn't a *Terminator* in the actual sense, but nevermind.

Comment: Thanks. The posters are helpful. While I realise that it isn't a subtitle/tagline, I'm asking why this is the case. IOW, please include your explanation of the title in your answer. IMO, you could also read the title as Salvation *by* Terminator from the POV of Skynet as well as the resistance. Marcus was originally designed to be Skynet's salvation too, wasn't he?

Comment: Could be, but I think you are really reading too much into the title. I have given you a very plausible (and actual) reason for this, you are making it out to be more than it is. Besides, your original question was, "*Why the colon?*" and that is what I answered.

Comment: Actually, my question clearly states that the original titles follow a "title: subtitle" template and wonders why _Terminator Salvation_ doesn't. Providing an answer which essentially states that this is because _Salvation_ is not a subtitle is simply being pedantic as that is largely self-evident. The producers have chosen to retain the template, but not quite, as they want to make the title more than what it seems to be.

Comment: Like I said ... reading *way* too much into what is actually just a title. I'm glad you feel your question is ostentatious.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility might also be that the producers wanted to emphasize the fact that they were starting something new. *Terminator Salvation* was the first movie to be set in the future war against the machines instead of the present with the classic time-travel context and it was also initially planned to start a new trilogy (most probably set entirely in the future).

So in order to emphasize those aspects and distinguishing it from the previous movies, that title change might have been a conscious decision and might have been followed through in future upcoming sequels to it (which don't seem too likely anymore, though, given the *reboot* planned for 2015).